# pytorch logsumexp for tensors with different shapes

Tags: logging, pytorch, tensor, exp

I'm looking for ways to use torch.logsumexp with two tensors with different shapes. I currently implemented logsumexp manually like this below:

```
import torch
# t1.shape = (4,1,3)
t1 = torch.tensor([[[ 2,  1,  4]],[[-8, 23, -7]],[[ 8, -3,  3]],[[-4,  4,  6]]]).float()

# t2.shape = (4,6,3)
t2 = torch.tensor([[[ 3, 2, 2],[-1,-5, 1],[ 1, 1, 2],[-6, 7,-7],[ 3,-7, 1],[ 1,-1, 2]],
                   [[ 2, 1, 1],[ 3, 3,-1],[-5, 2, 4],[ 4, 3,-9],[ 1, 5, 1],[ 8,-5,-6]],
                   [[ 4, 6, 4],[ 1, 7,-7],[ 8, 8, 6],[-2, 1,-1],[ 9, 5, 9],[ 9, 2,-7]],
                   [[ 2,-6, 1],[-9, 9, 8],[ 3, 3, 2],[-3, 7, 4],[-6, 8,-5],[ 2, 4,-2]]]).float()

# t3.shape = (1,6,3)
t3 = torch.tensor([[[-1,-1, 0],[ 2, 2,-2],[ 3,-1, 0],[ 1, 0, 1],[ 2, 0,-1],[ 1,-2, 3]]]).float()

exp1 = torch.exp(t1)+torch.exp(t2)
log1 = torch.log(exp1)

exp2 = torch.exp(t1)+torch.exp(t3)
log2 = torch.log(exp2)
```

I would like to perform logsumexp for t1 and t2 and for t1 and t3. Because of exp and log operation, my code is very numerically unstable, so I'm hoping to use torch.logsumexp().

Is there any way to use torch.logsumexp() for those t1,t2, and t3 tensors? Or is there any way to make it numerical stable?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to perform this. I could simply just use

> torch.logaddexp

```
import torch
# t1.shape = (4,1,3)
t1 = torch.tensor([[[ 2,  1,  4]],[[-8, 23, -7]],[[ 8, -3,  3]],[[-4,  4,  6]]]).float()

# t2.shape = (4,6,3)
t2 = torch.tensor([[[ 3, 2, 2],[-1,-5, 1],[ 1, 1, 2],[-6, 7,-7],[ 3,-7, 1],[ 1,-1, 2]],
                   [[ 2, 1, 1],[ 3, 3,-1],[-5, 2, 4],[ 4, 3,-9],[ 1, 5, 1],[ 8,-5,-6]],
                   [[ 4, 6, 4],[ 1, 7,-7],[ 8, 8, 6],[-2, 1,-1],[ 9, 5, 9],[ 9, 2,-7]],
                   [[ 2,-6, 1],[-9, 9, 8],[ 3, 3, 2],[-3, 7, 4],[-6, 8,-5],[ 2, 4,-2]]]).float()

# t3.shape = (1,6,3)
t3 = torch.tensor([[[-1,-1, 0],[ 2, 2,-2],[ 3,-1, 0],[ 1, 0, 1],[ 2, 0,-1],[ 1,-2, 3]]]).float()

res1 = torch.logaddexp(t1, t2)
res2 = torch.logaddexp(t1, t3)
```